# Slideshow disappear when used in a scrollview

Tags: react-native, scrollview, slideshow

I'm trying to use the package "react-native-timed-slideshow". It's working fine but when I want to add text below and use it in scrollview, it disappear, I just have the text.

How can I manage to use scrollview with this package?

```
  <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TimedSlideshow
            items={items}
            showProgressBar={false}
            titleStyle={styles.h1slide}
            textStyle={styles.textfooter}
            renderCloseIcon={() => {
              styles.closeImgWrapperSlideshow,
                styles.closeImgWrapperSlideshow,
                null;
            }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.h3}>{i18n.t("Actus.text")}</Text>
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working if you put your slideshow in a view with a defined height.

To do so :

import Dimensions,
then :  `const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");`

and then you can do this for example :

```
<ScrollView vertical={true}>
  <View style={{ height: height / 2 }}>
    <TimedSlideshow
      items={items}
      showProgressBar={false}
      titleStyle={styles.h1slide}
      textStyle={styles.textfooter}
      renderCloseIcon={() => {
        styles.closeImgWrapperSlideshow,
          styles.closeImgWrapperSlideshow,
          null;
      }}
    />
    <Text style={styles.h4}>Blablablabla</Text>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```